# Clicking on inbox notifications ... ends up "slightly" in the wrong place?

Tags: bug, notifications, mobile-web

I have seen this a few times by now, and I am wondering whether this is a real UI bug, or just some sort of strange glitch:

- I open meta.stackexchange (or stackoverflow.com, or meta.stackoverflow.com) in my mobile device (iOS, using Safari)
- I see that I have one or more inbox notifications
- I open the notifications, and click on one of them
- Safari opens the corresponding page ... but doesn't show me the message I just clicked on. Instead, the browser shows me some other content, like another answer that sits below/above the response I just tried to get to.
- And note: the "message" that "notified" me still exists. It is not like the message was deleted in the meantime.

Comment: Might be a deleted comment or answer, in such case you'll reach the answer or the question page itself without anything highlighted.

Comment: No, I can scroll to the "message" that "notified" me. It is there.

Comment: Android 8 or 9 (Safari / Firefox): same behaviour. An `#anchor` problem?

Comment: Can you get a screencap of this? I can't reproduce on my phone for either the mobile web view or full site view. Which version of iOS on what hardware?

Comment: If I could solidly repro it, I would have said so ;-( .... iPhone 11 pro, latest greatest iOS (my devices always have latest greatest OS versions). So, no, I can't do a screencap.

Comment: Even iPhones allow screen capture, volume up and lock at the same time.

Comment: @DanK I can't solidly repro the issue. So I can't guarantee to give a screen capture. It would probably make more sense that I really pay a lot of attention, and when it happens again, I memorize where I "ended up" in detail.

Comment: I see, so it's an inconsistent bug or glitch